# if condiation and group by condiation not work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have `mark` table. i store all subject mark here. i store `like` `gpa=3.5` or `gpa=F` 
Now i want to make `marksheet` so i need `group by` . i want if one student get any subject `gpa =F` then result sheet show just only `Fail/f`

**Query Here**

```
CREATE VIEW result as SELECT name as name,roll as roll,class as 
class,subject_name as subject,exam_type as exam_type,sum(full_mark) as 
full_mark,sum(getmark) as getmark, if(gpa =='f', 'F',sum(gpa)) as 
total_gpa FROM mark GROUP by roll,class,exam_type
```

**Table**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that the `IF` is applied after the `SUM` and the `SUM` simply treats values of gpa that are strings (e.g. `'f'`) as 0 values meaning that the `SUM` is always numeric (and never equal to `'f'`). What you need to do is check the gpa value as you `SUM` it, then use a special value in that case (e.g. -9999) to make the result e.g. < 0, then you can test for the sum being < 0 and use that as the condition to give an 'F' result e.g.

```
IF(SUM(IF(gpa='f' OR gpa='F',-9999,gpa)) >= 0,
      CAST(SUM(gpa) AS CHAR), 'F') AS total_gpa
```

Note that because one output of the `IF` is text, we have to cast the `SUM` as text too to get the correct result.

I've created a small demo on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7706ae/8):

```
create table grades (id int, gpa varchar(20));
insert into grades values (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 'f');
select IF(SUM(IF(gpa='f' OR gpa='F',-9999,gpa)) >= 0,
          CAST(SUM(gpa) AS CHAR), 'F') AS total_gpa
from grades 
group by id
```

Output:

```
total_gpa
9
F
```

Comment: Some problem `IF(SUM(IF(gpa='f' OR gpa='F',-9999,gpa)) >= 0,CAST(IF(subject_type=1, SUM(gpa)-2 /count(subject_name) ,SUM(gpa)/COUNT(subject_name)) AS CHAR), 'F') as total_gpa` Every time work `else`  contation `IF(subject_type=1, SUM(gpa)-2 /count(subject_name) ,SUM(gpa)/COUNT(subject_name))` . not work if contation . Help me again

Comment: @HasanSheikh I'm not sure what you're saying. Can you please create a demo on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to show me? You might also want to consider creating a new question, as I won't have a lot of time over the next few days to look at it.

Comment: @HasanSheikh btw I created a new demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/889256/1) but it doesn't show a problem.

Comment: how can mention you my new question

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that? You can just use the "Ask Question" button to start a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277421/mysqli-everytime-work-only-else-condation-not-work-if-codation