# mysqli every time work only else condition but not if condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

**Here Is My Query**

```
CREATE VIEW marksheet as
SELECT name as name, student_id as student_id, 
roll as roll, class as class,exam_year as exam_year, 
subject_name as subject, exam_type as exam_type,
sum(full_mark) as full_mark, sum(getmark) as getmark,
department as department,
IF(SUM(IF(gpa='f' OR gpa='F',-9999,gpa))>=0, 
CAST(IF(subject_type=1,SUM(gpa)-2/count(subject_name),SUM(gpa)/count(subject_name)) 
AS CHAR), 'F') as total_gpa
FROM mark
GROUP by roll, class, exam_type
```

**Not work**

`IF(subject_type=1,SUM(gpa)-2/count(subject_name),SUM(gpa)/count(subject_name))`

Every time work only `else` condation `SUM(gpa)/count(subject_name`

Not work `subject_type=1,SUM(gpa)-2/count(subject_name)`

**My Table**

[image]

Result : gpa = 5+8+4+6

```
         = 23
```

But subject_type = 1 `so ,minus -2` (not work)

```
         = 21 (Not work)
```

Final Gpa = 21/count(subject_name)

Comment: Why are you dividing by `count(subject_name)`?

Comment: total subject `like = 7 or 9 ...`

Comment: So you're trying to get an average?

Comment: yes  i try `(total_gpa)/total_subject` if have any `extra subject` then `minus (-2)` form total `gpa`

Comment: So do you subtract 2 if ANY subject has `subject_type=1` or subtract 2 for EVERY subject that has `subject_type=1`?

Comment: yes , if  `subject_type=1`  got then subtract `2`

Comment: If 2 subjects are type 1, do you subtract 4 or just 2?

Comment: no . every student have only one subject `extra` mean `subject_type=1` so subtract  only 2 if have any subject `subject_type=1` or not subtract

Comment: I got problem . query ok but problem here when we  make `group by` only  check first `colum` not check other `colum` . now how can check all `colum`

Comment: What do you mean by "only check first colum"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can be only one extra subject (i.e. subject with `subject_type=1`) and all other subjects have `subject_type=0`, you can use `MAX(subject_type)` to determine if a student took an extra subject. This query should do what you want (note that you also need `()` around `SUM(gpa)-2`):

```
CREATE VIEW marksheet as
SELECT name as name, student_id as student_id, 
roll as roll, class as class,exam_year as exam_year, 
subject_name as subject, exam_type as exam_type,
sum(full_mark) as full_mark, sum(getmark) as getmark,
department as department,
IF(SUM(IF(gpa='f' OR gpa='F',-9999,gpa))>=0, 
CAST(IF(MAX(subject_type)=1,(SUM(gpa)-2)/count(subject_name),SUM(gpa)/count(subject_name)) 
AS CHAR), 'F') as total_gpa
FROM mark
GROUP by roll, class, exam_type
```

I've created a simplified demo at [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/280168/1).

Comment: don't nick mind can i get your facebook account link .

Comment: @HasanSheikh I'm not on facebook. SO is my social network.

Comment: any Communication link `like skype or others` please

Comment: @HasanSheikh sorry this is all I have

Comment: then what problem ? you have please send link